# How to remove index.php from codeigniter on Bitnami MAMP stack

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, bitnami

I have been developing using Bitnami MAMP stack 5.6.19 on my Macbook

I'm now ready to upload it to my server, but before that I want to remove the index.php from the site url and test it on my Mac so I can address any bugs.

I have tried changing the httpd-app.conf, httpd-prefix.conf as suggested on the Bitnami site, but no luck. I get a 404 error from the page.

Here is the **httpd-app.conf**

I change `AllowOverrite` from `None` to `All`

```
<Directory "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://codeigniter-fpm"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>

</Directory>
```

Here is the **httpd-prefix.conf**

I added `DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs"` and commented out the `Alias's`

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs"
#Alias /codeigniter/ "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs/"
#Alias /codeigniter "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs"

Include "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

In the codeigniter config I changed `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

I can't edit that the *.htaccess* file, cause I can't locate it and from what I understand Bitnami changed the app so you don't need to change *.htaccess*

Comment: please google for 'how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter'?

Comment: For hint you need to use htaccess.

Comment: @Juan-Emil Saayman add a file named as .htaccess on root folder and add this code into it <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @Gulshan Thank you for your help. I wish you had added your above comment as an answer so that I could accept it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a .htaccess file in root folder and paste this code into it.

htaccess Module:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] </IfModule>
```

Regards :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `http://www.your-site.com` instead of `index.php`, and, of course, replace `your-site` with your website name.