# Removing index,.php from codigniter on xamp not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have installed codigniter on xamp but I have searched on google and have tried many things but stil when I type in address it shows me object not found but when I add index.php it is working fine how do I remove index.php and make it work properly

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywebsite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

This is my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '/mywebsite';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

This is my routes .php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'c404';
$route['post/(:any)/(:any)'] = "blog/viewPost/$2";
$route['category/(:any)/(:any)'] = "blog/viewPostcategory/$2/$1";
$route['search'] = "blog/search";
$route['symbol/(:any)'] = "companies/view/$1";
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090166/how-to-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-on-bitnami-mamp-stack/42110082#42110082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base url should be:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/
```

And you shouldn't need this  in your htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /mywebsite
```

Comment: Still coming as object not found

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove 
 `RewriteBase /mywebsite` from .htaccess

2) Make sure `mod_rewrite`  is enabled

3) Make sure your `$config['base_url']` is correct

4) Your `.htaccess` file must be in root directory of your project and not of application directory

**.htaccess** file

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Stil not working yes the .htaccess file is located on main root means mysite folder

Comment: I am using xamp server

Comment: IS `mod_rewrite` on? Have you check it? Check my edited anwser

Comment: yes it is on LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 1):

ensure .htaccess file is inside of mywebsite/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mywebsite';
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost/mywebsite`